# PHP/MySQL text and reference

Tags: php, mysql, reference

So let's say that I got 2 variables in my MySQL table. First is nickname "David" and second is link to his website "http://davidswebsite.com". Second row is "Sam" and "http://samswebsite.com".

So now I want to have this on my site like this:

David
Sam

and when you click on one of these names ure redirected to their websites. Can you help me? Got no idea how to even start it. I am just newbie about php.

Regards.

Comment: Just put these 2 variables in a simple html code - `echo '<a href=$website>$name</a>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, create 3 columns.

id, name, then the url.

then output it like this

```
<a href="$url"><p>$name</p></a>
```

But I would like to tell you frankly that this question is very basic, this forum may hinder you from learning if you did not challenge yourself. :)

Comment: Yeah. As I look for it its looking really easy and like basic! Thanks for answer. Didn't try it yet but looks like it should work.

Comment: Noted on that, if you encounter problems don't hesitate to ask more questions. :)